# Back-end bound while copying array

Tags: c++, vectorization, intel-vtune

Im trying to analyze algorithm and I would like to improve some parts. Now I discover (in Intel VTUnes) that one function have back-end bound. Body of this function is:

```
int i, j;

// copy original population to temporary area
for (i = 0; i < population_size; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < problem_size; j++)
    {
        ffa_tmp[i][j] = ffa[i][j];
    }
}

// generational selection in sense of EA
for (i = 0; i < population_size; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < problem_size; j++)
    {
        ffa[i][j] = ffa_tmp[Index[i]][j];
    }
}
```

`ffa` and `ffa_tmp` are dynamically allocated 2D arrays of doubles. `Index` is array of integeres. It is used for ordering.
The worst part by analyzer is `ffa[i][j] = ffa_tmp[Index[i]][j];`

If I understand correctly, I could improve this with vectorization. Or there is another solution?

Comment: How does `Index` look like, and what does it contain?

Comment: oh, sorry for this.. Index[i] contains integers. It is used for ordering.

Answer (score 0):

You could improve this code using [memcpy](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memcpy/).

Answer (score 0):

Vectorization is definitely a way to go, but with a C++ twist. *dynamically allocated 2D arrays* aren't 2D arrays. They are an array of pointers to arrays. They can also be brutally and painfully slow due to all the jumping around through memory the CPU probably has to do. This is almost certainly part of what the tuner is warning you about. If you need to speed this up, first see if you can use a contiguous data store to improve the caching and reduce the pointer-chasing. [Here's a simple one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2076668/4581301).

Next comes `fa[i][j] = ffa_tmp[Index[i]][j]];`. Depending on how `Index[i]][j]` is arranged, the CPU may be having to jump back and forth through `ffa_tmp` looking for the indexed entry. Modern processors are at their absolute best when data access if contiguous and predictable (See [Why is processing a sorted array faster than processing an unsorted array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227809/why-is-processing-a-sorted-array-faster-than-processing-an-unsorted-array)). There isn't much you can do to improve the cache friendliness of that. If the first suggestion doesn't give you the performance improvement needed, see if you can redesign to avoid having to do this indexing entirely.

Comment: Thanks for reply. This looks good. But I wonder, If I use Matrix class from the link.. how can I create function which will return part of array? So i could use somethink like `matrix(i)` and I get `*double` for `i`

Comment: If you're looking for a row  you could `double* Matrix::operator()(size_t i) { return &mData[i * mCols]; }` and access like a normal array. But I think I'd be more inclined to make `const` and non-`const``slice` functions that do pretty much the same thing or returns a `row_view` class depending on just how much data protection I need.